# How to show that $[-2,2)$ is not compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> How to show that $[-2,2)$ is not compact?

I can show that $(-2,2)$ is not compact since $K=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-2,2-\frac{1}{n})$ has no finite subcover.

However I'm not sure how I can write a union of open sets which will include $-2$?

Comment: In the relative topology, $[-2,x)$ is open, where $-2<x<2$

Comment: How about $(-3, 2 - 1/n)$?

Comment: This is a good thing to be cautious about, but in this case it turns out to not make a difference: the entire space $[-2,2)$ is necessarily open, for example, as is $[-2,0)$. This will be clear if you look at how the subspace topology is defined.

Comment: $\{(-2.1,-1.9)\}\cup\{(-2,2-1/n)\}$ has no finite subcover

Comment: @Pedro Doesn't the cover have to equal the space? So in this case the cover must equal $[-2,2)$?

Comment: You can for example take $\{ (-2+1/t, 2-1/t) \mid t>1 \ldots \}$. The union of this family covers $[-2, 2)$.

Comment: @md2perpe:  $-2$ is not in that union, is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open cover of \[0,1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468314/open-cover-of-0-1)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. Oops... I was thinking of $\{ (-2-t, -2+t) \mid 0<t<4 \}$ and somehow got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Your set is bounded, but not closed as $2 \in \overline{[-2,2[}$ (because for example $(2-1/n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $[-2,2[$ converging to $2$).

Alternatively,

$$\{[-2,2-1/n[\}_{n=1}^\infty$$

is an open cover of $[-2,2[$ (with the relative topology!) without finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

Compact implies sequentially compact.  Consider $x_n=2-1/n$.  The limit, $2$, is not in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Using the relative topology of the subset [$-2,2$) where the open sets are [$-2$,b) so:

$\cup^{\infty}_{i=1}A_i$ where $A_i$ are the open sets $A_i$ = [$-2$,$2-\frac{1}{i}$) and with this covering it is impossible to obtain a finite sub cover.